# How to avoid duplicates when finding all k-length substrings

Tags: c, string, substring, unique

I want to display all substrings with `k` letters, one per line, but avoid duplicate substrings. I managed to write to a new string all the `k` length words with this code:

```
void subSent(char str[], int k) {
    int MaxLe, i, j, h, z = 0, Length, count;
    char stOu[1000] = {'\0'};
    
    Length = (int)strlen(str);
    MaxLe = maxWordLength(str);

    if((k >= 1) && (k <= MaxLe)) {
        for(i = 0; i < Length; i++) {
            if((int)str[i] == 32) {
                j = i = i + 1;
            } else {
                j = i;
            }

            for(; (j < i + k) && (Length - i) >= k; j++) {
                if((int)str[j] != 32) {
                    stOu[z] = str[j];
                } else {
                    stOu[z] = str[j + 1];
                }
                z++;
            }
            stOu[z] = '\n';
            z++;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm struggling with the part that needs to save only one time of a word.

For example, the string `HAVE A NICE DAY`
and `k = 1` it should print:

```
H
A
V
E
N
I
C
D
Y
```

Comment: What should `HAVE A NICE DAY` and `k=2` (or `k=3`) look like? Are duplicate letters removed in every case? If so, are the cases for `k=2` and `k=3` shown wrong in the selected answer? It is unclear what your ultimate objective is, and unclear whether the answer provided satisfies it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `subSent()` routine poses a couple of challenges: first, it neither returns nor prints it's result -- you can only see it in the debugger; second it calls `maxWordLength()` which you didn't supply.

Although avoiding duplicates can be complicated, in the case of your algorithm, it's not hard to do.  Since all your words are fixed length, we can walk the output string with the new word, k letters (plus a newline) at a time, doing `strncmp()`.  In this case the new word is the last word added so we quit when the pointers meet.

I've reworked your code below and added a duplication elimination routine.  I didn't know what `maxWordLength()` does so I just aliased it to `strlen()` to get things running:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define maxWordLength strlen

// does the last (fixed size) word in string appear previously in string
bool isDuplicate(const char *string, const char *substring, size_t n) {
    for (const char *pointer = string; pointer != substring; pointer += (n + 1)) {
        if (strncmp(pointer, substring, n) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void subSent(const char *string, int k, char *output) {
    int z = 0;

    size_t length = strlen(string);
    int maxLength = maxWordLength(string);

    if (k >= 1 && k <= maxLength) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length - k + 1; i++) {

            int start = z;  // where does the newly added word begin

            for (int j = i; (z - start) < k; j++) {

                output[z++] = string[j];
                while (string[j + 1] == ' ') {
                    j++;  // assumes leading spaces already dealt with
                }
            }

            output[z++] = '\n';

            if (isDuplicate(output, output + start, k)) {

                z -= k + 1;  // last word added was a duplicate so back it out

            }

            while (string[i + 1] == ' ') {
                i++;  // assumes original string doesn't begin with a space
            }
        }
    }

    output[z] = '\0';  // properly terminate the string
}

int main() {
    char result[1024];

    subSent("HAVE A NICE DAY", 1, result);

    printf("%s", result);

    return 0;
}
```

I somewhat cleaned up your space avoidance logic but it can be tripped by leading spaces on the input string.

**OUTPUT**

```
subSent("HAVE A NICE DAY", 1, result);

H
A
V
E
N
I
C
D
Y

subSent("HAVE A NICE DAY", 2, result);

HA
AV
VE
EA
AN
NI
IC
CE
ED
DA
AY

subSent("HAVE A NICE DAY", 3, result);

HAV
AVE
VEA
EAN
ANI
NIC
ICE
CED
EDA
DAY
```

Comment: Why are you printing the full string, including duplicate characters, in the `2` and `3` char-per-line cases? Shouldn't they also be done with duplicate letters removed from the string, or am I just missing the point? e.g. *"remove duplicate letters from the string as a whole."*??

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, I understand your point.  I read his problem as  removing the duplicate K length words from the result.  Although the question says "letters", that seems to be due to edits by others.  I latched onto "struggling with the part that need to save only one time of a word".)  Such that , "DONT MISS MISSISSAUGA" would only output one "ISS", instead of three, with a kmer length of 3.  If the OP confirms, beyond simple acceptance, I can edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I was reading though the question and answer and was trying to resolve all the issues, and they just didn't all fit. Who knows. Looks like you got him pushed in the right direction as there has been no further response. Good job.